# Dimension mismatch error when comparing strings with '=='

Tags: matlab

Here is my code:

```
a='abc';

key = input('Enter secret: ', 's');

if key =='abc'
fprintf('Correct')
else
fprintf('Wrong. Re-enter.');
end
```

When I run the code, I enter `abcdefg`, it shows an error:

> *Error using ==, matrix dimension must be agree.*

How do I prevent such an error?

Comment: Use [strcmp](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) for comparison of strings instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` doesn't work when matrices have different dimensions. `'abc'` is really a 1x3 character array. When comparing strings, [`strcmp`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) or [`strcmpi`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) should be used. An alternative is [`isequal`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html), but I'd recommend using one of the other two.